# Why did not found return type in Custom UDAF of presto

Tags: emr, presto

Custom Function what I made did not work in presto on EMR.

I want to create a simple UDAF that just return `42`.

First, my custom function what I wrote a simple functions, but did not work in presto.

A error is following in `presto-cli`:

```
presto> select answer_to_life('the universe');
Query 20180324_120433_00000_7n6s6 failed: answer_to_life(varchar):bigint not found
com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: answer_to_life(varchar):bigint not found
        at com.facebook.presto.metadata.FunctionRegistry.doGetSpecializedFunctionKey(FunctionRegistry.java:972)
        at com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader$FunctionToCacheLoader.load(CacheLoader.java:146)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3716)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2424)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2298)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2211)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4154)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4158)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:5147)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5153)
        at com.facebook.presto.metadata.FunctionRegistry.getSpecializedFunctionKey(FunctionRegistry.java:898)
        at com.facebook.presto.metadata.FunctionRegistry.getAggregateFunctionImplementation(FunctionRegistry.java:875)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.buildAccumulatorFactory(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:1973)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.planGlobalAggregation(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:1984)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitAggregation(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:955)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitAggregation(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:596)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.plan.AggregationNode.accept(AggregationNode.java:167)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitExchange(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:1919)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitExchange(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:596)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.plan.ExchangeNode.accept(ExchangeNode.java:196)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitAggregation(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:952)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitAggregation(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:596)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.plan.AggregationNode.accept(AggregationNode.java:167)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitOutput(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:638)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitOutput(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:596)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.plan.OutputNode.accept(OutputNode.java:82)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner.plan(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:393)
        at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LocalExecutionPlanner.plan(LocalExecutionPlanner.java:324)
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution.<init>(SqlTaskExecution.java:161)
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution.createSqlTaskExecution(SqlTaskExecution.java:121)
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecutionFactory.create(SqlTaskExecutionFactory.java:71)
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTask.updateTask(SqlTask.java:340)
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskManager.updateTask(SqlTaskManager.java:321)
        at com.facebook.presto.server.TaskResource.createOrUpdateTask(TaskResource.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor311.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
        at io.airlift.http.server.TraceTokenFilter.doFilter(TraceTokenFilter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at io.airlift.http.server.TimingFilter.doFilter(TimingFilter.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:673)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:591)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Code of AggregationFunction is following.

I referenced to this [presto code](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/46402324e4fc990098c06b4fe33147425b13a56d/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/operator/aggregation/AverageAggregations.java)

```java
package sample;  

import com.facebook.presto.spi.block.BlockBuilder;  
import com.facebook.presto.spi.function.*;  
import com.facebook.presto.spi.type.BigintType;  
import com.facebook.presto.spi.type.StandardTypes;  
import io.airlift.slice.Slice;  

@AggregationFunction("answer_to_life")  
public final class AnswerToLife {  
    private AnswerToLife() {  

    }  

   @InputFunction  
   public static void input(@AggregationState NullState state, @SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR) Slice value) {  

    }  

   @CombineFunction  
   public static void combine(@AggregationState NullState state, @AggregationState NullState other) {  

    }  

    @OutputFunction(StandardTypes.BIGINT)  
    public static void output(@AggregationState NullState state, BlockBuilder out) {  
        BigintType.BIGINT.writeLong(out, 42);  
   }  
}
```

Detail code is here (https://github.com/asari-mtr/presto-udaf/tree/stackoverflow).

The structure what I deployed is follwoing:

```sh
$ ls -1 /usr/lib/presto/plugin/my-udaf/
commons-codec-1.4.jar
guava-21.0.jar
hive-udf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
presto-array-0.197.jar
stats-0.155.jar
presto-udaf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I use `emr-5.12.0`(`Presto 0.188`)

Thank you for your time.

---

**Edited1**

list in jar file.

```
% jar -tf target/presto-udaf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/services/
sample/
META-INF/services/com.facebook.presto.spi.Plugin
sample/AnswerToLife.class
sample/AnswerToLifePlugin.class
sample/NullState.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/sample/
META-INF/maven/sample/presto-udaf/
META-INF/maven/sample/presto-udaf/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/sample/presto-udaf/pom.properties
```

sever.log

```
$ grep answer -i  /mnt/var/log/presto/server.log
2018-03-26T06:37:14.213Z        INFO    main    com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager        Installing sample.AnswerToLifePlugin
2018-03-26T06:37:14.214Z        INFO    main    com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager        Registering functions from sample.AnswerToLife
```

And execute `show funcstions`

```
presto> show functions;
            Function             |                     Return Type                     |                                 Argument Types
---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ST_Area                         | double                                              | Geometry
 ST_AsText                       | varchar                                             | Geometry
 ...
 answer_to_life                  | bigint                                              | varchar
 ...
```

---

**Edited2**

Delete `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.facebook.presto.spi.Plugin`

Add `<packaging>presto-plugin</packaging>` to pom.xml

https://github.com/asari-mtr/presto-udaf/commit/f2a2ddbf0339e08f418b378a7ead511020e98a3b

I deployed zip made by Maven under `/usr/lib/presto/plugin/`.

But, The contents of the error does not change.

---

**Edited3**

I got the source from github (branch 0.188) on my Mac and built presto.

When we placed the above UDAF on its presto, it worked perfectly.

Perhaps there is a mistake in the installation procedure for presto on EMR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!

The Custom plugin did not work because it was not a plugin creation, but a way of deploying on EMR was wrong.

Since I did not deploy to all nodes in the procedure I performed, I confirmed the operation by registering the following shell as a bootstrap action.

```sh
#/bin/bash
aws s3 cp s3://hogehoge/presto-udaf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip /tmp/
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/presto/plugin/
sudo unzip -d /usr/lib/presto/plugin/ /tmp/presto-udaf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

- [10.1. SPI Overview — Presto 0.198 Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop/spi-overview.html)

> Plugins must be installed on all nodes in the Presto cluster
>   (coordinator and workers).

- [Create Bootstrap Actions to Install Additional Software - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/us_en/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html)

> You can use a bootstrap action to copy objects from Amazon S3 to each
>   node in a cluster before your applications are installed. The AWS CLI
>   is installed on each node of a cluster, so your bootstrap action can
>   call AWS CLI commands.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote there are two things which are missing.

- make sure that you used maven packaging `presto-plugin` in your pom.xml
- also implement `com.facebook.presto.spi.Plugin` which in `getFunctions` method would return your function.

Take a look in `presto-geospatial` Presto module and see `com.facebook.presto.plugin.geospatial.GeoPlugin` and its pom.xml as reference.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.
But I already used Maven, and implemented `getFunctions`.  (There is all code in github.  https://github.com/asari-mtr/presto-udaf/tree/stackoverflow)

Comment: `com.facebook.presto.spi.Plugin` file should be generated. No point of having this in your source code.

Have you restarted Presto? Have you seen in Presto logs that your plugins is loaded during the Presto startup?

Comment: Also use LongState. State has to be serializable and instantiable.

Comment: Add a postscript.I have generated `com.facebook.presto.spi.Plugin` (https://github.com/asari-mtr/presto-udaf/blob/stackoverflow/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.facebook.presto.spi.Plugin). And I have restarted.

Comment: There is no difference between LongState and NullState, but is LongState preferred? (https://github.com/asari-mtr/presto-udaf/blob/stackoverflow/src/main/java/sample/NullState.java)

Comment: I delete the file `com.facebook.presto.spi.Plugin`, and add `presto-plugin` in my pom.xml. But, the same error occurred.(https://github.com/asari-mtr/presto-udaf/commit/f2a2ddbf0339e08f418b378a7ead511020e98a3b)

Comment: Can you try with `SELECT answer_to_life('the universe') FROM tpch.tiny.nation GROUP BY name`

Comment: The same error occurred `answer_to_life(varchar):bigint not found`. I saw `(FunctionRegistry.java:972)`, but it is an error when signature is not registered as I got the answer at first. Is there any way to check if it is registered other than `show functions`?